# I am trying to reverse the string so it can read letter y as vowel in it

Tags: c

I am reversing the string so for example if I input word 'try' it would read y as a vowel and print out the word is legal.

The reverse function works but it doesn't pass to the switch statement value.

#include 
    //#include

```
void rev(char *);
void legal(char string);

int main()
{

     char string[50];
     char temp;
     printf("Enter any string:");
     scanf(" %s",&string);
     //printf("Before reversing the string %s\t",string);

     rev(string);
     printf("\nReverse String is %s",string);
     temp = legal(string);
     printf("\nReverse String is %s",temp);

return 0;
}

void legal(char string)

{   


      switch(string)
    {
    case 'A':
    case 'E':
    case 'I':
    case 'O':
    case 'U':
    case 'Y':
    case 'a':
    case 'e':
    case 'i':
    case 'o':
    case 'u':
    case 'y':
    printf("\nWord is legal");
    break;
    default:    
    printf("\nWord is not legal");  
    break;
    }

return 0;    

}


//reversing string using pointers
void rev(char *str)

{
     char *str1,temp;
     str1=str;
     while(*str1!='\0')
     str1++;                  
     str1--;                                  
     while(str<str1)
     {
        temp=*str;                  
        *str=*str1;                  
        *str1=temp;                  
        str++;
        str1--;
     }
}
```

Comment: you should have break for each case.

Comment: I don't see how extra breaks would help.  How can you even call legal?  It expects a char but you are passing a pointer to a string.  How does it even compile?

Comment: @ChristianMark You only need a break for each case if you want a different action for each case. Otherwise it will simply execute the action for all the statements until it reaches a break, which is fine because they all have the same action.

Comment: My guess is OP is confusing a switch statement with a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

I see you have mistaken a `char *` with a `char`.

Instead, you must loop through the string, character by character and figure out with a flag if the word is legal or not..

here is how I would do it, not tested code ahead:

```
void rev(char *);
void legal(char *string);

int main()
{

     char string[50];
     int temp;
     printf("Enter any string:");
     scanf(" %s",&string);
     //printf("Before reversing the string %s\t",string);

     rev(string);
     printf("\nReverse String is %s",string);
     temp = legal(string);

     printf("\nLegal? %d",temp);

return 0;
}

int legal(char *string)
{   
    char *ch = string;
    int flag = 0;
    while(*ch != '\0'){
     switch(*ch)
     {
    case 'A':
    case 'E':
    case 'I':
    case 'O':
    case 'U':
    case 'Y':
    case 'a':
    case 'e':
    case 'i':
    case 'o':
    case 'u':
    case 'y':
      flag = 1;
    break;
    default:    
      //nothing  
    break;
    }
   }
   if(flag == 1){
      printf("word is legal!");
   }else{
      printf("word is illegal!");
   }
    return flag;    
}
```

Comment: i've compiled your example and compiler gives me an error for switch(string) line -- statement requires of integer type.

Comment: ah, I modified my code, that part just slipped my mind @user2876750

Comment: Ok.This is my main function now  int main()
    {
        char string[50];
        
        int i = 0;
        printf("Enter any string:");
        scanf(" %c",&string[i]);
        
       
        legal(string);
        
 }
It compiles with no errors, but it's not doing anything. Any ideas?

Comment: @user2876750 yeah, your main function is totally messed up, let me just write the whole program for you, maybe that will run..

Comment: I ran it and for some reason it gives Time limit exceeded  time: 5 memory: 2296 signal:24  error. Try running in ideone.

Answer (score 0):

C++ doesn't allow string or arrays in switch instructions, that might be the problem.

Plus you're assigning tempt to 0.

Comment: In C, each char corresponds to it's integer ASCII value, so 'a' is read as an integer of 97. This makes chars okay for switch statements.

Comment: lol this code has a couple errors. He's passing in an array and running it through the switch as an array.

Comment: I wasn't calling you up on it. I was saying there's more than one error in this code, inferring I was pointing out another error. +1 for valid point haha

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in your code.

`void legal(char string);` returns a void, but you attempt to assign it here:

```
temp = legal(string);
```

`legal` takes a char, but you try to pass a `char []` to it.

You `return 0;` in legal.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the variable `string` is an array, while `legal` only accepts single char values. You can fix this by accepting a pointer or an array or some combination there-of and only checking the first digit if that is what you want.

Your corrected code would look like this:

```
void legal(char *string);
```

and then inside the legal function, you can reference the first character as `*string`.